# Proxy Forward based on FQDN

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy

I'm attempting to robust and secure my home network a bit better. One of my current projects is to setup a proxy server that forwards to servers on my internal. Instead of having multiple ports open, I can have 80 and 443 pointing to this one server. Unfortunately, one of my servers (server2) is my projects server and is running multiple webapps on different ports.

Here is how I envision it looking:

1. Proxy server receives https://server1.internal.com
2. It handles request to https://server1.internal.com
3. Proxy receives https://server2a.internal.com
4. It forwards to https://server2.internal.com:8080
5. Proxy receives https://server2b.internal.com
6. It forwards to https://server2.internal.com:8081

I don't have issues manually specifying each forward as there aren't that many. I just haven't been able to find out how to do this. Additionally, each internal server is running Let's Encrypt certbot so port 80 needs to be reachable (forwarded) to each for cert renewal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna straight configuration - you could describe all your servers on your server1 (if server1.internal.com is your proxy for server2) like this.

```
upstream internal1 {
  server server1.internaal.com;
}

upstream server2a {
  server server2.internal.com:8080;
}

upstream server2b {
  server server2.internal.com:8081;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server1.internal.com;

  location /.well-known {
    #root of your project on this server
    #or directory where lays .well-known
    root /var/www;
  }

  #other insecure requests will receive 301 redirect to https
  location / {
    return 301 https://server1.internal.com$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server2a.internal.com;

  #proxy .well-known to server with certbot
  location /.well-known { proxy_pass https://server2a; }

  #all other requests receives redirect to https
  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

#the same for server2b
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server2b.internal.com;

  #proxy .well-known to server with certbot
  location /.well-known { proxy_pass https://server2a; }

  #all other requests receives redirect to https
  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name server1.internal.com;

  location / {
    root /var/www/html;
    #all other options for server1
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name server2a.internal.com;

  ssl_certificate ...;
  ssl_certificate_key ...;
  #other ssl options...

  #proxy all requests to upstream named server2a
  location / {
    proxy_pass https://server2a;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name server2b.internal.com;

  ssl_certificate ...;
  ssl_certificate_key ...;
  #other ssl options...

  #proxy all requests to upstream named server2a
  location / {
    proxy_pass https://server2b;
  }
}
```

but if you have only one entry point and a trusted network between your servers, you don't have to keep certbot on the second server and generally use https for communication between nginx-proxy and your applications. Let the first server handle certbots and https from the user to the server and forward requests from the user to the applications.

Comment: Allow me to clarify, as it seems there was some confusion in my wording. Proxy server is separate from server1 and server2(a,b). The (reverse) proxy would the single entry point for all traffic to those servers from the outside. Additionally, I'm trying to keep all of my internal traffic encrypted as well, which is why I was keeping certbot running on each of the internal servers. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok. Then you should just change server{} with server1.internal.com and make it like all other servers.